# Confirmation before submitting only one button using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I use ASP.NET MVC 5. I have several buttons.

I want use a confirmation before submitting a form but I am using 5 or more submit buttons.

I would like using Display jQuery dialog  (more pretty than confirm dialog).

I want confirmation dialog for only button (Logout) and call Action Logout in my Controller.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <button type="submit" name="btnComida" value="Comida" class="btn btn-primary" @((Model.DeshabilitadoComida) ? "disabled = 'disabled'" : "")>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Comida.png" width="48" height="48" /> Comida
        </button>

        <button type="submit" name="btnMedico" value="Medico" class="btn btn-primary" @((Model.DeshabilitadoMedico) ? "disabled = 'disabled'" : "")>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Medico.png" width="48" height="48" /> Médico
        </button>

        <button type="submit" name="btnSalida" value="Salida" class="btn btn-primary" @((Model.DeshabilitadoSalida) ? "disabled = 'disabled'" : "")>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Salida.png" width="48" height="48" /> LOGOUT
       </button>

   }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @freedomn-m I only confirmation dialog if the user click de Logout button, not another buttons.

Comment: Make the logout button `<button type="button">` and hook into its `click` event.